# Link to Assets field doesn't work when multiple sites are listed in parameters

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager

I'm using Assets to display pdf documents with race results from a news page. This is an MSM site, and the problem I'm having is on the secondary sites. 'results_pdf' in the following code is an Assets field. If the entry is being drawn from the main site, the link to the results_pdf works fine. If the entry is from the secondary site, the link does not work. However, if I remove 'default_site' from the parameters, and the entry is from the secondary site, the results_pdf works fine. So the link is correct, but having multiple sites listed is causing a problem. The non-Assets fields work correctly. I'm using Assets 2.1 with EE 2.5.5. Suggestions on how to fix this?

Thank you
Susan

```
{exp:channel:entries site="default_site|nwisa" channel="news_and_results|news_and_results" category="25|31|35|36|37|" limit="1"}        
<h3>{title}</h3>   
{full_post}
<div class="button"><a href="{results_pdf}">Event Results</a></div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: What is the actual output? ie: what is wrong about the image link for the one from the second site?

Comment: It should be opening a pdf in a new tab. Instead, on the secondary site with 2 sites listed in the parameters, it opens a new tab, with the same page opening. No pdf. So if the link is located on Page A, instead of opening a pdf in a new tab, Page A opens a 2nd time in the new tab. But if I remove the mention of default_site, the pdf will open correctly.

Comment: Additional information - I find that if I change the 'results_pdf' field from an Assets field to an EE file field, I don't have the same issue. The pdf opens correctly for entries for each of the sites. So I could do that. But, I would prefer to use Assets if I can get it working properly, because that pdf is used in another channel that has another Assets field, and if the client uploads the pdf to an EE file field on the News page, he won't see it in the Assets field in the other channel unless it gets synced, and will end up uploading it a 2nd time.

Comment: Susan, can you show us the rendered link in the template when using Assets?  Seeing the actual outputted code (rather than the input from the template) would help quite a bit I suspect. Thank you!

Comment: Lisa - Do you mean the code that is output when viewing the page source? If so, it's as follows with an empty link:
<div class="button"><a href="" target="_blank">Event Results</a></div>

Comment: BUT if I just remove the site="default_site|nwisa" from the parameters, then it changes to:

<div class="button"><a href="http://nwisa.hssailing.org/documents/2012-2013-results/2013trchamps.pdf" target="_blank">Event Results</a></div>

Comment: Susan, is Super Admin access available to this site? I'd love to troubleshoot directly. If so, please email details to support@pixelandtonic.com. Thank you!

Comment: Lisa - I'm sorry, but I can't give SuperAdmin access now. I did find one additional thing. It seems to be specifically the default_site that is the issue. If I put 2 sites in the parameters (other than the default_site), the Results link works correctly for Results from both sites, but if one of the 2 sites is the default_site, them the link for the Results of the 2nd site does not work.

1. site="default_site|nwisa" - default_site Results work, but NWISA Results comes up empty.

2. site="pcisa|nwisa" - both Results links work
And if I use a File field instead of Assets, they all work.

Comment: Hey Susan - are you having any other troubles with Assets? Are they all indexed?  And did you try with Assets 2.1.3?  Also, is there any chance at all of getting this on a dev box for troubleshooting?  Direct access would be invaluable, it sounds like you've got a bit of an odd one there...

Comment: Hey Lisa and Susan ... I'm using EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.1.3 ... and I'm getting the same issue.  It's exactly as Susan describes. If there are multiple site short names listed in the "sites=" parameter, the sub-sites images do not show.  Any help is much appreciated.